# Fan Only operation not working - gas forced air furnace

Tags: wiring, furnace, gas, fans

So i followed online guidance to enable "fan only" mode for my forced air gas furnace,  Essentially that was to connect the "G" terminals on the t-stat and the furnace board.  Seems simple enough, but it does not seem to work, so i am wondering if it is not possible???   Before i go tearing into Murphys Law stuff like a broke wire etc, any sage advice is appreciated.  Thanks  Jim

Comment: Model # of furnace?

Comment: Yes, can we have a make/model # and/or a wiring diagram for your furance please?

Comment: Make is Rheem Model is Criterion II #RGPH-012EARJR, I wish i had the wiring diagram sorry

Comment: Assuming I found the right (or close enough) manual, it should support continuous fan mode. Do you know which other wires are connected between the thermostat and the furnace?

Comment: White-W, Green - C, Blue -Rh  Thats it  Like you say it should work, so i will look for continuity issues with the wires. Thank you